# Get all type from product when search by type

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 database tables are

```
Product(id, name)

Type(id, name)

ProductType(id, product_id, type_id)
```

Now i want to search all the product by specified type, but the result will be those products with all of it's types.

*For example product 1 have 3 type call type_1, type_2 and type_3, i will search all product with type_1 and type_2 and i want the result will be*

| id | product_id | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | 1 |
| 2 | product1 | 2 |
| 3 | product1 | 3 |

My query is

```
SELECT Product.id as product_id, ProductType.type_id
FROM Product
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ProductType on Product.id = ProductType.product_id
WHERE ProductType.type_id in (1,2)
```

The result is

| id | product_id | type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | 1 |
| 2 | product1 | 2 |

and i want it to be like i expected up there

Comment: I don;t understand: why should something with `TypeId = 3` show up in the results?

Comment: RIGHT OUTER JOIN does not seem logically correct for your stated goal - something what you might notice if your sample data were more realistic. And your ID column in ProductType serves no useful purpose - stop applying patterns blindly.

Comment: INNER JOIN not RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the `product_id`s that you want with aggregation in the table `ProductType`:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM ProductType
WHERE type_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- the number of types that you search for 
-- or maybe:
-- HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) = 2
-- if there are duplicate types for each product_id
```

You can use the above query to select from the table `Product`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM ProductType
    WHERE type_id IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```